# How to obtain the moment of inertia of the rotor?

Tags: dc-motor, simulink

I need to measure or calculate the moment of inertia of the rotor in order to simulate a DC motor in computer simulation. Is there a procedure that can be followed to measure or calculate the moment of inertia without special lab equipment? Thanks

Comment: There are some torsional pendulum methods that can found by searching the internet.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to identify the time constants from a step response?

Comment: You can use a weight on a string, wrapped around a shaft or pulley to accelerate the rotor. The applied torque is known. The acceleration of the rotor as the weight falls will allow you to approximate inertia. Assuming drag is low.

Comment: It's only useful to know the moment of inertia of a mtor if you're going to try and build some control system. So, suggest you just crack on and build a position servo with straight feedback to coil current. The circuit will oscillate (when you know the inertia you can stabilise it later). From oscillation frequency and the value of the position to current gain you used, you can calculate the effective rotor inertia.

Comment: Measure the mechanical time constant with and without a known inertia attached.

Comment: Measure the spin down rate from a known speed. Same again with a mass added to the rotor, with a known moment of inertia (flywheel). The two measurements can give you values for friction and unknown (rotor) moment of inertia.

Comment: If you have (or can make) an accurate model of the rotor something like Solidworks will calculate the moment of inertia about the centroid of mass.

Answer (score 1):

Pendulum with two thin steel wires. There is also a variation with four wires, in such case the equation differs a little.

[image]

Comment: if you're happy to dismantle the motor, this is good.